# A better way to trigger background images based on scroll

Tags: javascript, css, horizontal-scrolling

I am trying to create a horizontal scroller that when on scroll a div's background image will change.

The div has a character with an idle gif and when on scroll the gif should change to a walk cycle gif.

I have the concept semi working but my scroll method for changing the background is not solid.

```
var isScrolling = false;
console.log(isScrolling);

//changing the background od character based on scroll
function playAnimation() {
var Character = document.getElementById("character");
if (isScrolling == true) {
    Character.style.backgroundImage = 
"url(/images/gif/sqeekiWalk.gif)";
} else {
    Character.style.backgroundImage = 
"url(/images/gif/sqeekiIdle.gif)";
}
}

window.onmousewheel = playAnimation;

//Checking if the user is scrolling
(function( $ ) {
$(function() {
    var $output = $( "#output" ),
        scrolling = "<span id='scrolling'>Scrolling</span>" ,
        stopped = "<span id='stopped'>Stopped</span>"; 
        $( window ).scroll(function() {
            $output.html( scrolling );
            isScrolling = true;
            clearTimeout( $.data( this, "scrollCheck" ) );
            $.data( this, "scrollCheck", setTimeout(function() {
                isScrolling = false;
                $output.html( stopped );
            }, 250) );

        });
});
})( jQuery );
```

I expected the image to change on state of scroll but only changes at the end of the scroll section.

Comment: Welcome to SO @Luke. I'd suggest that as well as your JavaScript you include the HTML and CSS in the form of a code snippet so we can help.